# static_cast seems to work when it can't possibly work

Tags: c++, static-cast

In the following code I use `static_cast<B*>` on a `void*`, which points to an `A` object.

`A` and `B` are not related in any way. I understand the compiler cannot raise an error against this. But what I don't understand is, how come this actually seems to work when run...? I would expect a segfault or an error of some kind.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
    void f() const {
        cout << "f" << endl;
    }
};

class B {
    public:
    void q() {
        cout << "q" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    A a;
    void* p = &a;

    static_cast<B*>(p)->q(); // Prints "q"!

    return 0;
}
```

What is the mechanism behind this?

Comment: UB, if you want to call that a "mechanism".

Comment: Undefined behaviour means anything can happen ... surely you have been exposed to this concept by now

Comment: @M.M Haha, fair enough. It just seemed odd that *that* would be the way UB manifests itself... actually correctly calling the said function. So, I thought I might be missing something fundamental.

Comment: `would expect a segfault` That's not guaranteed, but if you really want a segfault, add some data members in  `B` and write to them inside `B::q()`.

Comment: You're welcome to check your compiler's assembly output to see what it does in this specific case at this specific optimization level. (If you do that, I recommend not using `<iostream>`.) The compiler is free to do whatever it thinks will make the resulting code run better, UB be damned. A compiler could look at this, see you always make a call to `q`, and simply call `q` with `p` as the object argument. It could also look at this, make assumptions while optimizing that this code breaks, and end up turning `main` into a noop when getting rid of paths that can't be reached.

Comment: in this case both your classes are super-simple, containing non-virtual function methods only. The compiler simply calls the function with an argument not used in the function. I'd say this should behave more or less correctly in most cases.

Comment: FYI: [`std::endl` is usually unnecessary](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#slio50-avoid-endl). Also, I believe a cast `T*`->`void*`->`U*` can be succinctly spelled `reinterpret_cast<U*>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code causes undefined behaviour (because it dereferences a `B *` which does not point to a `B` object), which means anything can happen. You should not expect any particular subset of consequences.

To find out what your compiler did, you could inspect the assembly. My guess would be that the compiler generated assembly which would be correct if there were a `B` object there: call the function `B::q()` with implicit argument `p`.

Comment: Another way to say it: in the absence of fanciness (esp. `virtual`), member functions are basically just free functions. Would you be surprised if `void f(A const*) { cout << "f\n" } void q(B*) { cout << "q\n" } int main() { A a; q(reinterpret_cast<B*>(&a)); }` worked? The compiler is just doing static dispatch. (Note that I believe my example *is* defined to work, while the question's is not.)

Comment: @HTNW yes, non-virtual members behave very much like free functions with a first argument that receives `this`. In fact, early C++ "compilers" worked by translating C++ to C and then invoking the C compiler , and that was how they would handle non-virtual member functions.

Answer (score 0):

> how come this actually seems to work when run...?

Because the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> I would expect a segfault or an error of some kind.

When behaviour is undefined, there is no guarantee that there would be a segfault or an error of some kind. It would generally be unreasonable to expect such. When behaviour is undefined, there are no guarantees whatsoever.